# TypeError after overriding the __add__ method

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how `__add__` works:

```
class MyNum:
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.num=num
    def __add__(self,other):
        return MyNum(self.num+other.num)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)
```

If I put them in a list

```
d=[MyNum(i) for i in range(10)]
```

this works

```
t=MyNum(0)
for n in d:
    t=t+n
print t
```

But this does not:

```
print sum(d)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'instance'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the **sum()** to work?

My problem is how to use the sum on a list of objects that support the `__add__`, need to keep it as generic as possible.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You need to define `__radd__` as well to get this to work.

`__radd__` is *reverse add*. When Python tries to evaluate `x + y` it first attempts to call `x.__add__(y)`. If this fails then it falls back to `y.__radd__(x)`.

This allows you to override addition by only touching one class. Consider for example how Python would have to evaluate `0 + x`.  A call to `0.__add__(x)` is attempted but `int` knows nothing about your class.  You can't very well change the `__add__` method in `int`, hence the need for `__radd__`. I suppose it is a form of dependency inversion.

As Steven pointed out, `sum` operates in place, but starts from 0.  So the very first addition is the only one that would need to use `__radd__`.  As a nice exercise you could check that this was the case!

Comment: Looks right to me. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218710/pythons-sum-and-non-integer-values

Comment: @hop:  David Heffernan is correct.  Implementing `__radd__` works.  I double checked with a test implementation of `__radd__` and it worked just fine.

Comment: @David Heffernan:  I know what `__radd__` does, but perhaps Ηλίας does not.  Include an explanation in your answer and I'll add my +1.

Comment: @Ηλίας: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218710/pythons-sum-and-non-integer-values/1218735#1218735

Comment: @Fred @Steven @Ηλίας @hop Sorry, I hope this is better now. I was leaving work in a hurry so could not elaborate.  I assumed that Google would do the rest.  Anyway, I think this is better now.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Who needs Google when you have SO!

Comment: What's with the downvote? Even the original without the explanation wasn't worth a downvote!

Comment: @Ηλίας re: "Who needs Google when you have SO", how do you think I answered this question? By the way, nice 'tache!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan We are Google's minions afterall!

Comment: btw -- I suggest returning NotImplemented if other does not have a .num attribute -- that way if other implements a fancier __add__ or __radd__ it can be used instead.

Answer (score 17):

```
>>> help(sum)
Help on built-in function sum in module __builtin__:

sum(...)
    sum(sequence[, start]) -> value

    Returns the sum of a sequence of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
    of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).  When the sequence is
    empty, returns start.
```

In other words, provide a start value:

```
sum(d, MyNum(0))
```

**Edit pasted from my below comment:**

`sum` works with a default start value of the integer zero. Your `MyNum` class as written does not know how to add itself to integers. To solve this you have two options. Either you can provide a start value to `sum` that has the same type as your class, or you can implement `__radd__`, *which Python calls when adding values of differing types* (such as when the first value in `d` is added to the default start value of zero).

Comment: @hop:  I tested this and it worked.  Could you expand on your comment?

Comment: So sum only works on if you subclass int? d=[MyNum(i) for i in range(10)] then sum(0,d) fails

Comment: @Ηλίας:  `sum` works with a default start value of the integer zero.  Your `MyNum` class as written does not know how to add itself to integers.  To solve this you have two options.  Either you can provide a start value to `sum` that is the same type of your class, or you can implement `__radd__`, which Python calls when adding values of differing types (such as when the first value in `d` is added to the starting value of zero).

Answer (score 1):

I oppose relaying on sum() with a start point, the loop hole exposed below,

```
In [51]: x = sum(d, MyNum(2))

In [52]: x.num
Out[52]: 47
```

Wondering why you got 47 while you are expecting like
…start from 2nd of MyNum() while leaving first and add them till end, so the expected result = 44 (sum(range(2,10))

The truth here is that 2 is not kept as start object/position but instead treated as an addition to the result

```
sum(range(10)) + 2
```

oops, link broken !!!!!!

Use `__radd__`

Here below the correct code. Also note the below

**Python calls `__radd__` only when the object on the right side of the + is your class instance**
eg: 2 + obj1

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class MyNum:
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.num=num

    def __add__(self,other):
        return MyNum(self.num+other.num)

    def __radd__(self,other):
        return MyNum(self.num+other)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)

d=[MyNum(i) for i in range(10)]
print sum(d)    ## Prints 45
d=[MyNum(i) for i in range(2, 10)]
print sum(d)    ## Prints 44
print sum(d,MyNum(2))   ## Prints 46 - adding 2 to the last value (44+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyNum:
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.num=num
    def __add__(self,other):
        return self.num += other.num
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)

one = MyNum(1)
two = MyNum(2)

one + two

print(two.num)
```

Comment: OP is trying to understand code, but you simply dumped code without any explanation. Please [edit] your answer to include a description of your code and actually answer the question. If you don't want that, you may delete your answer since it is entirely not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is reduce (functools.reduce in Python 3.x).

```
from functools import reduce
from operators import add
d=[MyNum(i) for i in range(10)]
my_sum = reduce(add,d)
```