# Handle operation by object on right side (__r*__ methods)

Tags: python, operator-overloading, operators

How does `numpy` can handle operations, when `numpy.array` is on the right side?

```
>>> [1,2,3]+numpy.array([1,2,3])
array([2, 4, 6])
```

I thought `list` should try to add `array` (with `list.__add__` method) to itself and **fail**.

---

Additional example to @M4rtini's answer: `__radd__` is called when `__add__` fails and objects are of different types:

```
class A():
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return "result"
print(A()+A()) #fail with TypeError
```

Comment: `__radd__` get's called when `__add__` fails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with \_\_add\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082190/help-with-add)

Comment: It may not be a direct duplicate, but the answer there explains this behavior

Comment: @M4rtini comment on update please

Comment: `__radd__` won't get called for two objects of the same type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A(object):
    def __radd__(self, other):
        print ("__radd__ called of A")
        return "result of A"

class B(object):
    def __radd__(self, other):
        print ("__radd__ called of B")
        return "result of B"


print (B()+A())
print (A()+B())

>>__radd__ called of A
>>result of A
>>__radd__ called of B
>>result of B
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)

> ```
> object.__radd__(self, other)
> object.__rsub__(self, other)
> object.__rmul__(self, other)
> object.__rdiv__(self, other)
> object.__rtruediv__(self, other)
> object.__rfloordiv__(self, other)
> object.__rmod__(self, other)
> object.__rdivmod__(self, other)
> object.__rpow__(self, other)
> object.__rlshift__(self, other)
> object.__rrshift__(self, other)
> object.__rand__(self, other)
> object.__rxor__(self, other)
> object.__ror__(self, other)
> ```
>
> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations
>   (+, -, *, /, %, divmod(), pow(), **, <<, >>, &, ^, |) with reflected
>   (swapped) operands. **These functions are only called if the left
>   operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands
>   are of different types**. [2]

Comment: Where is it stated in Python docs that `__radd__` is called on fail, and that it's not called with objects of the same types? i couldn't figure that out for several days:)

Comment: Clearly stated, my fault