# how do I get my class to control the addition operation when the class instance is on the right?

Tags: python, class

consider my class `mint`

```
class mint(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __add__(self, other):
        o = other.i if isinstance(other, mint) else other
        return mint(1 + self.i + o)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.i)
```

It's designed to do another kind of addition.

```
a = mint(1)

a + 1 + 2

6
```

However, adding while my object is on the right doesn't work.

```
1 + a
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-519-8da568c0620a> in <module>()
> ----> 1 1 + a
> ```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'mint'
```

---

***Question: How do I modify my class such that `1 + a` will work?***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5082229/6394138

Comment: As well as implementing `.__radd__` as shown below, also consider implementing [`.__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__).

Comment: venturing outside of `pandas`, I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__):

```
class mint(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __add__(self, other):
        o = other.i if isinstance(other, mint) else other
        return mint(1 + self.i + o)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.i)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other

a = mint(1)
print(1 + a)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Here's explanation from Python docs:

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations (+, -, *, @, /, //, %, divmod(), pow(), **, <<, >>, &, ^, |) with reflected (swapped) operands. These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types. [2] For instance, to evaluate the expression x - y, where y is an instance of a class that has an **rsub**() method, y.**rsub**(x) is called if x.**sub**(y) returns NotImplemented.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `__radd__`

```
In [1]: class mint(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, i):
   ...:         self.i = i
   ...: 
   ...:     def __add__(self, other):
   ...:         o = other.i if isinstance(other, mint) else other
   ...:         return mint(1 + self.i + o)
   ...: 
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return str(self.i)
   ...:         
   ...:     def __radd__(self, other):
   ...:         return self.__add__(other)
   ...:     

In [2]: a = mint(1)

In [3]: 1 + a
Out[3]: 3
```