# Adding zero to my complex number class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm creating my own complex number class (not using Python's built in one) and I'm running into a problem when I try to add zero to my complex number. For reference this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "display.py", line 25, in __init__
t.color(mandelbrot(c).getColor())
File "C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\Python\mandelbrot.py", line 10, in __init__
z = z*z + self.__starting_value
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'complex'
```

Where self.__starting_value is the complex number.

The addition definition goes as follows:

```
class complex:
    def __init__(self, a = 0, b = 0):
        self.__real = float(a)
        self.__imag = float(b)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return complex(self.__real + other.__real, self.__imag + other.__imag)
```

The solution should be simple enough but I am still learning Python and could use the help.

Comment: can you post the code and the stack trace please !

Comment: Does it work when you add *any* plain integer to an instance of your class?

Comment: It wont work with any integers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError after overriding the \_\_add\_\_ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082190/typeerror-after-overriding-the-add-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You are only handling addition of a `complex` object to a `complex` object, when you want to also be able to handle `complex` object + int.
2. When adding in this order (int + custom type), you need to add a reflected addition method (`__radd__`)

---

```
class complex:
    def __init__(self, a = 0, b = 0):
        self.__real = float(a)
        self.__imag = float(b)
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, complex):
            return complex(self.__real + other.__real, self.__imag + other.__imag)
        else:
            return complex(self.__real + other, self.__imag)
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other
```

N.B.: It is considered bad style to shadow built-in names (like `complex`).

Comment: Thanks! The complex class is just for practice :)

Comment: @yojo890 I'm not suggesting you don't practice, I just suggest renaming it to `Complex` (with an upper-case c).

Answer (score 0):

`int` + `complex` will first try to use`int.__add__`. `complex` + `int` will first try to use `complex.__add__`.

You need to implement `complex.__radd__`. See the related note in [Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/numeric-types.html):

> These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types.

You will need to handle the case where `other` is `int` in both `complex.__add__` and `complex.__radd__`.

Answer (score 0):

`__add__` is for addition when the left-hand-side operand is of the type you're writing. When Python fails to call the `int` `__add__` method, it tries `__radd__`. If you define `__radd__` (with the same behavior), you'll get the result you want.