# Summing class instances

Tags: python, object, sum

I'm trying to use the built-in function `sum()` on a list of objects and get object as a result.

Here's an extract of my code:

```
class vector:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return vector(self.x+other.x, self.y+other.y)

l = []
l.append(vector(3, 5))
l.append(vector(-2, 3))
l.append(vector(0,-4))

net_force = sum(l)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'instance'
```

I guess that's because `sum()` initially sets the result to 0 and then iterates over the list, but I can only define adding things to `vector`, not the other way round.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218710/pythons-sum-and-non-integer-values

Comment: Why do you create a new `vector`-object in the `__add__()`-function? Why not `self.x += other.x; self.y+=orther.y`?

Comment: @msvalkon Because that would be completely wrong. You don't want `a = b + c` to modify `b`, you want it to create a new vector and name it `a`. You may be thinking of `__iadd__`.

Comment: ah yes, of course, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your starting condition (see [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)):

```
net_force = sum(l, vector(0, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your other option is to modify `__add__` slightly to special-case this, i.e.

```
class vector(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        if other == 0:
            return self
        else:
            return vector(self.x+other.x, self.y+other.y)
```

Which would enable `sum` to work without specifying initial conditions....

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
net_force = vector(0,0)
for i in l:
    net_force += i
```

or else maybe you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082190/help-with-add).

Comment: It works, but it's not quite pythonic. Thanks for the post mentioning `__radd__`, though.