# Sum a list of object attributes

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a class defined as

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self,other):
        return MyClass(self.value + other.value)

    __radd__ = __add__
```

I would like simply to apply the `sum` function to them like this:

```
a=MyClass(value=1)
b=MyClass(value=2)

c=[a,b]
print sum(c)  # should return a MyClass instance with value 3
```

as was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218710/pythons-sum-and-non-integer-values). However, an exception is raised:

```
     15 
     16 c=[a,b]
---> 17 print sum(c)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'MyClass'
```

I don't understand why the `sum` function wants to add two different types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) needs somewhere to *start*; by default, it starts at `0`. So the first operation it attempts is `0 + MyClass(value=1)`, which you haven't told it how to do!

You therefore have two choices, either:

1. Specify the `start` (e.g. `sum(c, MyClass())`); or
2. Tell `MyClass` how to deal with adding integers to instances.

The latter could look like:

```
class MyClass(object):

    ...

    def __add__(self, other):
        try:
            return MyClass(self.value + other.value)  # handle things with value attributes
        except AttributeError:
            return MyClass(self.value + other)  # but also things without

    ...
```

which lets you skip the explicit `start`:

```
>>> sum([MyClass(1), MyClass(2)]).value
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `sum(iterable[, start])` sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. `start` defaults to 0.

You can modify the class by

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        if (isinstance(other, MyClass)):
            return MyClass(other.value + self.value)
        else:
            return MyClass(other + self.value)

    __radd__ = __add__
```

Comment: I see, thanks ! I need then to initialize my sum by setting for example: 
sum(c,MyClass(0))

Comment: @LongDoCao that is one way of solving the problem, yes. Should `MyClass` instances be able to be added to integers?

Comment: @jonrsharpe : not in my case, but this is good to know anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yup, sorry about that, I accepted the other answer because it just came before yours, and helped me understand what to do. I changed the accepted answer. cheers.